# Fetching Cloud Function Logs using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I want to fetch the execution logs for a given cloud function using the execution ID of that particular instance using a python script.
Is there a way to do that? Maybe using `google-cloud-logging` or similar?

Comment: Yes, use the library with the correct query string. What did you try up to now? What's your blockers?

Comment: you can use google-cloud-logging==3.5.0 in the "requirements.txt" file and add the related code into "main.py" as mentioned in the link.
https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-functions-best-practice-4-4-monitor-and-log-the-executions-22222aa25f1b

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "use the correct string" @guillaumeblaquiere!
That's precisely where I was wrong and I didn't realise I should focus on that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **google-cloud-logging** for fetching the execution logs for a given Cloud Function as mentioned below.

- Create a basic structure for Cloud Functions.
- Create a file “**requirements.txt**” inside your project folder and paste
  **google-cloud-logging==3.5.0**
  into the same file.

Add below lines to the **main.py** file.

```
from flask import Response
import google.cloud.logging
import logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client(project="project")
client.setup_logging()
# logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

def main(request):
   try:
       logging.debug("I am a debug log!")
       logging.info("I am a info log!")
       logging.warning("I am a warning log!")
       logging.error("I am a error log!")
       logging.critical("I am a critical log!")
       return Response(response = 'ok', status = 200)
              
   except Exception as e:
      
       logging.error("I am a error log!", e)
       return Response(response = 'AN ERROR OCCURED, see logs', status = 400)
```

Deploy the Function accordingly and this will make sure that the  executionId is correctly logged with logs, as well as the severity within stackdriver.

**Note :** The above information is derived from the [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-functions-best-practice-4-4-monitor-and-log-the-executions-22222aa25f1b) written by **Beranger Natanelic**.